# Question about Montels theorem/family of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let
$\mathbb{F}_1 =\{f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\hspace{0.4cm} \text{f holomorphic}, f(0)=f'(0)=1, |f''(z)|<3 \}$

$\mathbb{F}_2 =\{f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}\hspace{0.4cm} \text{f holomorphic},  |f'(z)|<1 \}$

I need help determining which of these family of functions would be having a convergent subsequence. So the functions are entire and their first, resp. second derivative is bounded, how can I deduct whether they are locally bounded or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with Liouville's theorem? If so, you can find an explicit description of both of these families.
Indeed, $f \in F_1$ satisfies that $f''$ entire and bounded, so constant by Liouville. Then using the two other conditions, $F_1$ is just the set of polynomials of degree 2 of the form $1+z+cz^2$ where c is a complex number such that $|c| < 3/2$.
For $F_1$ you can use the same reasoning and get a similar description.

Can you conclude from here?

Comment: Thank you very much, so the second one would be a polynomial of degree 1, $f(z)=cz+d$, $|c| < 1$, I don‘t have any other inital values here, bit I still have problems determining the convergent subsequence

Comment: For a local uniform bound, you can just apply a triangle inequality to get: $|1+z+cz^2| \leq 1 + |z| + 3/2 |z|^2$

Comment: Thanks, so following this argumentation, both families would be locally uniform bounded and thus fulfill Montel‘s theorem?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true.